# Rapid Miner + own algorithms

Tags: data-mining, rapidminer

How can i use user defined algorithms in Rapid miner 5.3?
We have various inbuilt algorithm in Rapid Miner 5.3.If i want to use an algorithm ,defined by  a user.

Comment: Rapidminer has an open source "community" edition. Have a look at the source code.

Answer (score 2):

The [RapidMiner extension template](https://github.com/rapidminer/rapidminer-extension-template) provides a skeleton to extend RapidMiner, though you can do a lot (using Groovy) with the [Execute Script](http://rapid-i.com/wiki/index.php?title=Execute_Script) operator (as described in the [How to Extend RapidMiner 5](http://rapidminer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/How-to-Extend-RapidMiner-5.pdf) document.) And there is the source of RapidMiner on GitHub as @Anony-Mousse told in a comment.